# How to assign a guest cart to a customer with rest API

Tags: magento2, cart, api, rest-api, pwa

How to assign a guest cart to a customer with rest API. I've try `PUT /carts/{cartId}` when I’m log as a customer to assign a guest cart to the customer https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/customer-rest-api.html#operation/quoteCartManagementV1AssignCustomerPut. If I’m trying right after I’ve log in I got a error because the customer already have a cart assign and if I try right after proccess the transaction, I’m getting 404 saying there’s not entity at the cartId

Comment: Does Magento not automatically assign the guest's cart to the customer when logging them in based on their session? In frontend it does this, but I'm not sure if it happens via API.

Comment: No, it doesn't. In the API docs it's mentionning this endpoint but the only time I got it work, it was right after I've create the customer with a brand new guest-cart. I didn't try with a processed guest cart.